# Source of predictions made by Swami Vivekananda

Tags: vivekananda, ramakrishna

In [this](https://youtu.be/7t6PZdpd5Mo) video, a monk of Ramakrishna Order says Swami Vivekananda has made four successful predictions.

1. That Europe will descend into chaos hinting at World Wars.
2. Proletariat revolution from China and Russia hinting at rise of communism.
3. India will get independence before 50 years from 1897.
4. India will rise in global position.

---

Where in Compete works of Swami Vivekananda are these predictions made? What was the context? Please answer with citing sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting below some passages in Swami Vivekananda's writing that deals with the questions asked.

**Prediction on Europe**

> The West is groaning under the tyranny of the Shylocks, and the East
> is groaning under the tyranny of the priests; each must keep the other
> in check. Do not think that one alone is to help the world. In this
> creation of the impartial Lord, He has made equal every particle in
> the universe. The worst, most demoniacal man has some virtues which
> the greatest saint has not; and the lowest worm may have certain
> things which the highest man has not. The poor labourer, who you think
> has so little enjoyment in life, has not your intellect, cannot
> understand the Vedanta Philosophy and so forth; but compare your body
> with his, and you will see, his body is not so sensitive to pain as
> yours. If he gets severe cuts on his body, they heal up more quickly
> than yours would. His life is in the senses, and he enjoys there. His
> life also is one of equilibrium and balance. Whether on the ground of
> materialism, or of intellect, or of spirituality, the compensation
> that is given by the Lord to every one impartially is exactly the
> same. Therefore we must not think that we are the saviours of the
> world. We can teach the world, a good many things, and we can learn a
> good many things from it too. We can teach the world only what it is
> waiting for. **The whole of Western civilisation will crumble to
> pieces in the next fifty years if there is no spiritual foundation. It
> is hopeless and perfectly useless to attempt to govern mankind with
> the sword. You will find that the very centres from which such ideas
> as government by force sprang up are the very first centres to degrade
> and degenerate and crumble to pieces. Europe, the centre of the
> manifestation of material energy, will crumble into dust within fifty
> years if she is not mindful to change her position, to shift her
> ground and make spirituality the basis of her life. And what will save
> Europe is the religion of the Upanishads.**

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 3, Lectures from Colombo to Almora, Reply to the Address at Paramakudi**

**Prediction on the rise of the working class**

> **Yet, a time will come when there will be the rising of the Shudra
> class, with their Shudra-hood; that is to say, not like that as at
> present when the Shudras are becoming great by acquiring the
> characteristic qualities of the Vaishya or the Kshatriya, but a time
> will come when the Shudras of every country, with their inborn Shudra
> nature and habits — not becoming in essence Vaishya or Kshatriya, but
> remaining as Shudras — will gain absolute supremacy in every society.**
> The first glow of the dawn of this new power has already begun to
> break slowly upon the Western world, and the thoughtful are at their
> wits' end to reflect upon the final issue of this fresh phenomenon.
> Socialism, Anarchism, Nihilism,6 and other like sects are the vanguard
> of the social revolution that is to follow. As the result of grinding
> pressure and tyranny, from time out of mind, the Shudras, as a rule,
> are either meanly senile, licking dog-like the feet of the higher
> class, or otherwise are as inhuman as brute beasts. Again, at all
> times their hopes and aspirations are baffled; hence a firmness of
> purpose and perseverance in action they have none.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 4, Translation: Prose, Modern India**

**Prediction on India’s rise**

> The present government of India has certain evils attendant on it, and
> there are some very great and good parts in it as well. Of highest
> good is this, that after the fall of the Pâtaliputra Empire till now,
> India was never under the guidance of such a powerful machinery of
> government as the British, wielding the sceptre throughout the length
> and breadth of the land. And under this Vaishya supremacy, thanks to
> the strenuous enterprise natural to the Vaishya, as the objects of
> commerce are being brought from one end of the world to another, so at
> the same time, as its natural sequence, the ideas and thoughts of
> different countries are forcing their way into the very bone and
> marrow of India. Of these ideas and thoughts, some are really most
> beneficial to her, some are harmful, while others disclose the
> ignorance and inability of the foreigners to determine what is truly
> good for the inhabitants of this country.
>
> **But piercing through the
> mass of whatever good or evil there may be is seen rising the sure
> emblem of India's future prosperity** — that as the result of the action
> and reaction between her own old national ideals on the one hand, and
> the newly-introduced strange ideals of foreign nations on the other,
> she is slowly and gently awakening from her long deep sleep. Mistakes
> she will make, let her: there is no harm in that; in all our actions,
> errors and mistakes are our only teachers. Who commits mistaken the
> path of truth is attainable by him only. Trees never make mistakes,
> nor do stones fall into error; animals are hardly seen to transgress
> the fixed laws of nature; but man is prone to err, and it is man who
> becomes God-on-earth. If our every movement from the nursery to the
> death-bed, if our every thought from rising at day-break till
> retirement at midnight, be prescribed and laid down for us in minutest
> detail by others — and if the threat of the king's sword be brought
> into requisition to keep us within the iron grasp of those prescribed
> rules — then, what remains for us to think independently for
> ourselves? What makes a man a genius, a sage? Isn't it because he
> thinks, reasons, wills? Without exercise, the power of deep thinking
> is lost. Tamas prevails, the mind gets dull and inert, the spirit is
> brought down to the level of matter. Yet, even now, every religious
> preacher, every social leader is anxious to frame new laws and
> regulations for the guidance of society! Does the country stand in
> want of rules? Has it not enough of them? Under the oppression of
> rules, the whole nation is verging on its ruin — who stops to
> understand this?

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 4, Translation: Prose, Modern India**

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer as always